# How to write unit test that use Robolectric to test the alpha value change of MenuItem?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have a `MenuItem` which is a send button `btnSend`, and I'm using **Robolectric** to write unit test. The unit test I'm going to do is like this: on the left side of the `btnSend`, there is a text view `txtFiled` which I added a listener, when this `txtFiled` is empty, `btnSend` alpha value is 70 which shows that it is disabled, when the `txtFiled` has some nonspace value, then `btnSend` alpha value is 255 which shows that it is enabled. I have some code like this

```
MenuItem sendItem = new RoboMenuItem(R.id.send);
sendItem.setIcon(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_send_light));
```

however, before and after I set the text view:

```
activity.txtField.setText("To");
```

The sendItem's alpha value is 0; I'm wondering why this is the case and how to write the correct unit test for this scenario. I debugged it and found that the listener gets called. Therefore I guess this is a fake created menu item. Thus its alpha value would not get changed.

I tried to get the menu item using shadow but could not even get the menu:

```
final CActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(CActivity.class).create().start().resume().visible().get();
activity.mTo.setText("To");
MenuItem sendItem = Shadows.shadowOf(activity).getOptionsMenu().findItem(R.id.send);
```

PS: I know to disable I need to use `setEnabled` to false, But user still should be able to click the button, and a `DialogFragment` will pop up to tell them why it is disabled.

Comment: I'd say it's not a scenario for a local unit test. This should be an instrumented test, e.g. using Espresso.

Comment: How do you set alpha for `MenuItem`?

Comment: @BartekLipinski agreed!

Comment: @EugenMartynov menuitem.getIcon().setAlpha();

Comment: Ok, looks like Robolectric doesn't work well with setting alpha to Drawable

Comment: @EugenMartynov yes

Comment: Create drawable by ShadowDrawable.createFromResourceId(int resourceId). Docs here http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.2/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowDrawable.html